# Display current record in MS-Access form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, record

I have a code now that will go to the next record, but in the form it will not display the next record just shows 0. You can see in the table that the code is working and going to the next record seeing that the quantity went down. Another problem is when switched to the next record and that one hits 0, I'm then getting a highlighted error on my `.Update` when I need it to go to the next one after that. It doesn't say an error, I just assume when it's highlighted then the problem is coming from that. Its basically like the code isn't restarting. Here is my code now:

```
Private Sub ItemCode_Dirty(Cancel As Integer)
Dim Db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set Db = CurrentDb

Set rs = Db.OpenRecordset("Select WrkordNum, ToGo from WorkOrders where ItemCode =" & Me.ItemCode)

With rs
    If Not .EOF Then
        If !ToGo <= 0 Then
            .MoveNext
        End If
        .Edit
        !ToGo = !ToGo - 1
        .Update

    End If
End With

End Sub
```

How do I get that next record to display in my form and not just show 0? What can I add in my code to have it restart to the beginning so that I works through the table and not just one record?

Comment: Don't use the `!` operator here. You can't control what that resolves to. Instead, use a fully qualified reference.

Comment: Include the error number and description in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You've opened a new recordset. This has no relation to your current form at all. You can do this from outside a form. You can even do this from Excel.

If you want to interact with the form you have to use form methods.

If you just want to go to the next record you would use code like this:

```
If Me.CurrentRecord < Me.Recordset.RecordCount Then
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acMoveNext
End If
```

If you want to move your form to the same record as your new recordset you would do this:

```
Private Sub ItemCode_Dirty(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim Db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    
    Set Db = CurrentDb
    
    Set rs = Db.OpenRecordset("Select WrkordNum, ToGo from WorkOrders where ItemCode =" & Me.ItemCode)
    
    With rs
        If Not .EOF Then
            If !ToGo <= 0 Then
                .MoveNext
            End If

            .Edit
            !ToGo = !ToGo - 1
            .Update

            Me.CurrentRecord = rs.AbsolutePosition
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

and finally, if you want to work with the current recordset instead of opening a new one:

```
Private Sub ItemCode_Dirty(Cancel As Integer)
    With Me.Recordset
        If Not .EOF Then
            If .ToGo <= 0 Then
                .MoveNext
            End If

            .Edit
            .ToGo = .ToGo - 1
            .Update
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The first one I placed where the 2nd 'If Statement' is and it did the count to 0, but when it got to 0 the vba code came up with '.Update' highlighted.

Comment: The second one the rs.CurrentRecord did not work. It wasn't an option for the rs.

Comment: The third one didn't subtract the amount of the ToGo.

Comment: Those are three different options. You're not supposed to use all 3. I gave you options because it's not clear from your question what you are doing. Please update your question to be more specific.

Comment: Yeah I know that, I didn't use them all at once. I tried each one separately to solve the issue. They all didn't work.

Comment: So debug. Nobody knows what "Didn't work" means but you.